# Get specific data from sqlitedatabase using row id

Tags: android

I have two columns in a database, id and city. How can I get all the city data and put it in a string when the row id is less than 3. I am having difficulty in writing a query to get data when the row id is less than 3. Right now my method gets all the data from the database. Thanks.

```
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CITY};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
String result =" ";
int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);

 int iCity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CITY);


for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){


result = result + c.getString(iCity)  + "\n"; 


}



return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CITY};

    // "note "rowid" is used in fts tables and "id" in normal tables.
    // I'm assuming your constant KEY_ROWID chose the correct one.

    String where = KEY_ROWID + " <= " + 3;  

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, where, null, null, null, null);


    if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Log.e("System.out", "cursor is empty");
    }else{

        int ix_city = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_CITY);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        do{
            String city = cursor.getString(ix_city);
            Log.i("System.out", "city name " + city);

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(city))
                  continue;

            sb.append(city).append("\n");
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        Log.i("System.out", "the entire list " + sb.toString());

    }
```

Comment: String where = KEY_ROWID + " <= " 3;// is there suppose be be semi- colon after 3 because it's giving an error

Comment: I missed a plus sign, but yes there is suppose to be a semicolon.  updated with the plus sign b/w opeartor and 3

Comment: error java.lang.reflect.method.invoke                                       com.android.internal.os.zygotinit.main

Comment: two things: 1) u can try to use your old code, and just steal the "where" clause...it should work, unless the wrong "rowid" vs "id" is chosen.  2) post full stack trace, showing line its crashing on (prolly in new question)... I'm not sure how that error relates to the code changes.

Comment: I used the your query with my old code and seems to work like a charm. Thanks